# GitLab-CI: How to build docker image from other repository?

Tags: git, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I would like to have all my dockerfiles in one repository, instead of having them in the seperate projects. Therefore I have created the project "conductor".
All my .gitlab-ci stages are also specified in "conductor".
In the actual project I only use the include command.

My current code:

```
docker build -f dockerfile .
```

Problem is that "dockerfile" isn't in the project where the pipeline gets executed but is in the "conductor" project.

How can i modify the -f parameter to take the dockerfile from another gitlab project?

Comment: ? Clone the repository and `-f /path/to/dockerfile` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
git clone https://gitlab.example.com/tanuki/awesome_project.git
```

to clone the remote repo. If the repo is not publicly accessible, you can create a [deploy token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/deploy_tokens/) to do this and use `git clone` with the deploy token.

```sh
git clone https://<username>:<deploy_token>@gitlab.example.com/tanuki/awesome_project.git
```

see: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/deploy_tokens/#git-clone-a-repository

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to have all my dockerfiles in one repository, instead of
> having them in the seperate projects. Therefore I have created the
> project "conductor". All my .gitlab-ci stages are also specified in
> "conductor". In the actual project I only use the include command.

It looks like a good usecase to define the generic stage/template in the common repository and to to include them in the users repositories via the `include` keyword.
Look at the [include documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#include) :

> include
> Use the include keyword to include external YAML files in your CI/CD
> configuration. You can break down one long gitlab-ci.yml into multiple
> files to increase readability, or reduce duplication of the same
> configuration in multiple places.

From user git repositories you could include the common template in the .`gitlab-ci.yml` such as :

```
include:
  - project: 'my-group/my-common-project'
    file: '/templates/.gitlab-ci-docker-build-template.yml'
```

And of course, reference the common stage(s) you need to use in it.
Note that the common templates are not ridid. User/consummer repositories may override some things. For example variables are overridable.

Answer (score 0):

The actual project could add conductor as a [Git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules) ([`git submodule add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-add-bltbranchgt-f--force--nameltnamegt--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--ltrepositorygtltpathgt).
In conductor, you would store your Dockerfile, one per actual project.

That way, your actual project can use

```
docker build -f conductor/dockerfile.actual
```